# Kivy update matplotlib graph with kivy.clock

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I have a matplotlib graph in my kivy app which I want to update every second with streaming data. So far what I have behaves a little weird. It does update but only when I resize my window a little

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.65
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
bar_canvas = fig.canvas

class Test(BoxLayout):
    catA = NumericProperty(0)
    catB = NumericProperty(0)
    catC = NumericProperty(0)

    #plot the bar graph
    def plot(self, dt):
        catA_rects = ax.bar(5, self.catA, width, color='g')
        catB_rects = ax.bar(6, self.catB, width, color='#808080')
        catC_rects = ax.bar(7, self.catC, width, color='r')
        ax.legend((catA_rects[0], catB_rects[0], catC_rects[0]), ('Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C'))


    #update the graph
    def update(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.plot,1)

    def classify_sample(self, test_sample):
        result_prob = classifier.predict_proba(test_sample)[0]
        result = classifier.predict(test_sample)[0]

        if result_prob.max() > 0.55:
            if result == 1:
                self.catA += 1

            else:
                self.catC += 1

        else:
            self.catB += 1



class ClassificationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        res = Test()
        res.bar_tab.add_widget(bar_canvas)
        res.update()
        return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClassificationApp().run()
```

In 'kv' file I call classify_sample to display the results inside a RecycleView Viewclass

```
Label:
    text: app.root.classify_sample(data)
```

I'm updating the `plot` function with `Clock.schedule_interval(self.plot,1)` which is working when I'm printing the output on the screen but the plot isn't getting updated when the value of `catA, catB or catC` changes
It only updates when I resize my app window a little
[image]

[image]

[image]

Also is there another way to add graphs other than matplotlib? Matplotlib wont work when I package this for android right?

Comment: where do you change the values of catA, catB and catC ?

Comment: @SPSP in another function which I call when input is given. The updates to catA, catB and C are working correctly when I'm printing the results inside the 'plot' function.

Comment: please post more code

Comment: @SPSP please take a look now, Thanks. P.S. using the 'on_change' methods also give the similar result. The properties are updating when I call print inside 'plot' function but graph still wont update unless I resize a little

Comment: I suggest you to schedule a function in the App class to redraw the whole box you can do that by adding an attribute root as an ObjectProperty by example in the app class and put the Test() there and your  plot function must edit that root.

Comment: @SPSP I tried doing it and made these changes https://pastebin.com/dFVDFPa3 but its still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making rather a silly error. After updating the graph in `plot` function I wasn't actually calling the `bar_canvas.draw()` method